# Java - regex - group separation

Tags: java, regex

I need to match entries like `{@x anything}` in strings like `a b c 1 225 {@x anything here1} test test {@x blabla} xyz test {@x any characters here}`. I tried `\{(@x ([^\}].*\w+(\.*)\s*)*)\}` so far, but this is not really what I want and I am kinda stuck :(

So that should get:

`anything here1`

`blabla`

`any characters here`

Comment: So, what's the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I mentioned `I tried .... so far`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: "({@x ([^{]*)})"

```
   String string = "a b c 1 225 {@x anything = here1} test test {@x bl** #abla} xyz test {@x any characters here}";        
    String regexp = "(\\{\\@x ([^\\{]*)\\})";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    while (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well to extract all groups that come with that structure you can start with:

```
{@x [a-zA-Z0-9 ]+}
```

From this point just remove the header and end of the requested strings and you should have the required output.

EDIT:

I've updated the regex a bit:

```
{@x [\w= ]+}
```

Comment: I might need to have special characters there, such as the equal (`=`) sign.

Comment: I think he says that he can have multiple special characters(not only the equal sign).

Answer (score 1):

Another try:

```
  String input="a b c 1 225 {@x anything here1} test test {@x blabla} xyz test {@x any characters here}";
  String pattern = "\\{@x [(\\w*)(\\s*)]*\\}";
  for( String s: input.split(pattern)){
      System.out.println(s);
  }
```

\w* = any word ( a-z,A-Z,0-9) ; *= 0 or more

\s* = white space ; *= 0 or more

[]* - repeating group.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
String string = "a b c 1 225 {@x anything here1} test test {@x blabla} xyz test {@x any characters here}";
String regexp = "\\{\\@x ([^\\}]*)\\}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

\{\@x - Matchers you start.

([^\}]*) - matches anyting except the end-curly (}) and puts that in a group (1)

\} - matches the end curly

Then you search and subtract your group.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to tell in pattern "match the minimum between characters '{' and '}'" so the pattern you can use is:

```java
    final String string = "a b c 1 225 {@x anything = here1} test test {@x bl** #abla} xyz test {@x any characters here}";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "\\{@x (.*?)\\}" ); // <-- pattern
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( string );
    while ( matcher.find() )
        System.out.println( matcher.group( 1 ) );
```

`?` in `.*?` is doing exactly that.